# Andersen casement windows show condensation and ice on the inside of the glass

Tags: windows

Our home in IL is 25 years old and during the last 2 - 3 winters we have experienced condensation and thick ice on the inside of most of the 30 windows we have in the home. We know several windows need to be replaced because they are foggy and streaky all year round.
Many contractors want to sell us brand new windows (price range: $25,000 to $70,000).
While we are contemplating our options (excluding new windows) on how to solve this problem we were wondering if anyone on this site has any idea: a) how to fix this problem or b) a contractor genre' that we could turn to for information and pricing? 
Thanks, 
John

Comment: Your indoor humidity is too high. Be sure it's appropriate for the outdoor air temperature.

Comment: Or you have too many cold air leaks around the window frame.   Since they are casement,are they closed AND latched/Locked during the winter season?  If not, that will create inside ice.  If there is condensation between the panes, that’s a different matter, those need replacement.

Comment: Is there no procedure for flowing dry nitrogen into the interior of these windows? It is shocking that Anderson windows would not last 50 years or more!

Answer (score 1):

Call Andersen windows and ask for a price to replace your windows.  Right now around Pittsburgh, Pa. they are giving a $300.00 discount for each replacement window. The sale ends November 4th. You may even be able to purchase replacement glass or replacement glass/sash that you can replace yourself if you are so inclined. Before you replace the glass and/or sash , check the sealing gaskets to make sure they are still OK. If you stay with Andersen windows they may have other options. I would call them, or "google" them for a phone number.

Comment: Intriguing. Any links to the offer?

Comment: I just  "googled" renewal by andersen clicked on the link and shazzam there was the add.

Comment: And yet... no link. The procedure doesn't work for me. Would you mind sharing?

Comment: I am not computer savey , so I do not know what you mean.  Come to my house and teach me. I just use google and search .

Comment: You'll want to Google "copy and paste". That's an invaluable skill to have. :)

Comment: d.george I took your advice and sent an e-mail to Andersen noting the condition of my windows. I am waiting for a call to set up an in-house appt for problem review, and cost to repair. Thanks, johnr